# How do I stop form input fields from resetting when 'cancel' is selected from confirm dialog box?

Tags: javascript, forms, dialog, confirm

I have a form with two buttons and an onclick js function:

```
  <button name='button1' onclick="backFn()">Change Date Range</button>
  <button name='button2' type='submit' form='form1'>Save</button>

  <script>
   function backFn() {
     let back = confirm("Any unsaved changes will be lost");
       if (back == true) {
          location.href = '/selectdate.php';
       } else {
     }
   }
  </script>
```

Button2 submits the form as required - no issue there.

Button1 triggers a function opening a confirm dialog box:
'OK' redirects as expected, but I want 'CANCEL' to close the dialog box but **retain** anything that's been written in the form.

At the moment the cancel option closes the dialog box, but clears the form.
How can I retain the form selections/text?
(If it's useful pressing 'back' afterwards repopulates the form.)

THANKS!

Comment: If button1 is in form it also submits form since default `type` is `"submit"`. Try `type="button"`. Beyond that, if you do a redirect everything in current page is gone

Answer (score -1):

Add type="button" to button1.

```
  <button name='button1' type="button" onclick="backFn()">Change Date Range</button>
```

Without this, the browser will assume the button is meant to submit the form.